# SQL Server : understanding default values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a database fundamentals course and 1 of the questions in the post-assessment is:

> Default values must be set for NOT NULL rows. True|False

I am led to believe that the answer is true because I answered false and it was wrong, the issue is that I don't understand why it is true.

If the question was:

> Default values must be set for NOT NULL columns when using ALTER TABLE to add a new column.

Then I know that is true and understand why. Am I misreading the question or am I misunderstanding something elsewhere?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Lee.

Comment: _Default values_ mean that when the value is _NULL_ it will take the _Default values_ insted, So is it true to set the column to _NOT NULL_?

Comment: I think that you’re right, let’s imagine we have a table with goods in stock for sale. What you can set as a default value for NOT NULL column PRICE?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Say we have a firstName and lastName column, both are NOT NULL, what default value would you have there? Surely you'd let the server respond required value?

Comment: Sometimes you see bugs in the code - sometimes there are bugs in the questions ;)
I'm quite sure you are right.

Comment: @LeeMorgan There is **NO** _Default value_ for such column(FirstName, LastName ...)

Comment: @Sami,  that's my point, so therefore the question and answer are wrong and I am right, now that I have confirmation I can move on safe in the knowledge I do indeed understand. Many thanks for all of your answers.

Comment: Yep, the question doesn’t even make sense, what is a NOT NULL *row*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  There is no requirement for a default definition when a column is declared `not null`.  This is quite apparent if you look at the [syntax diagram for `create table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql#default-definitions):

> ```
> <column_definition> ::=  
> column_name <data_type>  
>     . . . 
>     [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name [ DEFAULT constant_expression ] ]  
>     . . .  
>     [ NULL | NOT NULL ]
> ```

If the syntax where required, it would look more like this:

> ```
> <column_definition> ::=  
> column_name <data_type>  
>     . . . 
>     [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name [ DEFAULT constant_expression ] ]  
>     . . .  
>     [ NULL | NOT NULL [CONSTRAINT constraint_name] DEFAULT constant_expression ]
> ```

I'm not even sure that a default definition is a good idea for `not null` columns.  In many cases, you would want the `insert` to fail rather than inserting some artificial value.

The only relationship is when [altering tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql#syntax) that have data:

> If the new column does not allow null values and the table is not
>   empty, a `DEFAULT` definition must be added with the new column, and the
>   new column automatically loads with the default value in the new
>   columns in each existing row.

This is rather obvious.  The existing rows would be given a `NULL` value for the new column -- but the `NOT NULL` constraint disallows that, so a `DEFAULT` is needed.

Comment: many thanks for your explanation. I emailed the people that set the questions and they have now amended the question from row to column and corrected the answer. Lee